# switch data between columns in excel with a button

Tags: excel, button, swap, vba

What I would like to do is swap data from one column to another column or the other way around. Let me try to give an example.

I have a list of containers we use to deliver goods to a customer. As soon as those goods are delivered the container is empty and brought back, so available again. What I would like to do is have the list of containers in use on one side and on the other side a list of empty containers. 
In between I want to create two buttons that move the container to the other column ( >> and <<).

I have tried this myself and always failed. Eighter it doesn't work at all or I end up with a lot of blank spaces...

The best picture example I can give you guys is probably this:

[image: example image]

thank you all for your help!

Comment: photos got me shook. Maybe some sample data? Do you want to swap entire columns (Like `Col A to B`, and `Col B to A`)? Or just swap the values in a single row (Like `A2 to B2` and `B2 to A2`)?

Comment: I justs want the date to move from col A to B and B to A without leaving me with a list full of blanks.

Comment: **Entire column** or switch **Individual cells**?

Comment: Also, I think you uploaded the wrong photo.